# Добавить поле в dataframe со значениями из другого dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть два  dataframes:

```
d = {'date': ['2020-08-01 01:26', '2020-08-01 01:30', '2020-08-01 01:32', '2020-08-01 01:33', '2020-08-01 01:35'],
     'string': ['hello', 'world', 'friends', 'piece', 'great']}
df10 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df10
```

[image]

```
 d = {'date': ['2020-08-01 01:26', '2020-08-01 01:27', '2020-08-01 01:28', '2020-08-01 01:29', '2020-08-01 01:30',
              '2020-08-01 01:31', '2020-08-01 01:32', '2020-08-01 01:33', '2020-08-01 01:34', '2020-08-01 01:35',],
     'int': [10, 5, 18, 25, 3, 17, 11, 15, 4, 5]}
df11 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df11
```

[image]

Необходимо добавить поле 'int' в df10 таким образом, чтобы значения в нем соответсвовали значениям из полей 'date' и 'int' df11.

Мое решение:

```
for i in df10['date']:
    for y in df11['date']:
        if i == y:
            df10['int'] = df11['int']
```

Дает неверный результат:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Спасибо!

Comment: Что такое " поле 'int' в df3"??

Comment: это значения из поля int df11. Эти значения должны быть релевантны полю date df11. Т.е. во второй строке должно быть значение 3, в третьей строке 11 и тд

Comment: Это я все понимаю. Я спрашиваю, что такое df3?

Comment: Исправил! Ошибся немного

Answer (score 3):

В общем, я даже не буду приставать, причем тут "релевантность".

```
df11=df10.merge(df11, on="date")
```

Резульат:

```
               date   string  int
0  2020-08-01 01:26    hello   10
1  2020-08-01 01:30    world    3
2  2020-08-01 01:32  friends   11
3  2020-08-01 01:33    piece   15
4  2020-08-01 01:35    great    5
```

Оно? И впредь постарайтесь, пожалуйста, пользоваться общепринятой терминологией.

Comment: Нет не правильно. Вы добавили поле int в df11, а мне нужно в df10

Comment: df11 появилось того, как я не дождался вашего исправления в исходном вопросе -  уж больно долго вы думали.   Поняв, что никакого df3 (как вы написали в своем первоначальном вопросе) не существует, я использовал один из двух датафреймов, для которых это имело смысл.  Не угадал? Возможно. Надо поменять имя результирующего файла -  надеюсь, любой мало-мальски знакомый с pandas человек  легко справиться.

Answer (score 2):

Был сегодня похожий вопрос. делайте merge:

```
df10 = df10.set_index(["date"])
df11 = df11.set_index(["date"])
res = df10.join(df11, how ="inner").reset_index()
```

res:

```
               date   string  int
0  2020-08-01 01:26    hello   10
1  2020-08-01 01:30    world    3
2  2020-08-01 01:32  friends   11
3  2020-08-01 01:33    piece   15
4  2020-08-01 01:35    great    5
```